# selecting rows from mysql table in groups to display

Tags: mysql, select

I am parsing news articles from different websites and putting in a mysql table.

a typical days worth of parsing for a particular webiste and a particular category looks like this

```
===============================================================
id  source      category    article_link    create_ts
================================================================

1   A              1        article 1       2018-12-20 12:30:55
2   A              1        article 2       2018-12-20 12:30:55
3   A              1        article 3       2018-12-20 12:30:55
.
.
.
.
15  A              1        article 4       2018-12-20 12:45:15
16  A              1        article 5       2018-12-20 12:45:15
17  A              1        article 6       2018-12-20 12:45:15
.
.
.
55  A              1        article 7       2018-12-20 13:10:23
56  A              1        article 8       2018-12-20 13:10:23
57  A              1        article 9       2018-12-20 13:10:23
===============================================================
```

where:
A is a particular website like (for example) )BBC or CNN etc
1 like like a particular category like sports or headlines

what I want: is to display the last group first then secons last and then last
so i would like to see rows like

```
55
56
57
15
16
17
1
2
3
```

any idea how i can accomplish this

create_ts

Comment: what is the group seperator? how do you group your records. I believe that you need to have grouping column. or may be it is not clear for me yet

Comment: I am using create_ts for grouping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like simple order by statement

```
select  *
from Table1
order by create_ts desc, id asc;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85466b/4